# LocationManager and Networking in a Service

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, service, broadcast

I'm working on this project where I need Location updates plus data uploads even when the main Application is not in the foreground. I'm thinking of placing all location and networking functions in a Service (XService, for argument's sake) and communicate between the Activity (Main) and XService using broadcasts within the same process (no access for other apps).

I have not yet written the code, but the work flow goes something like:

> 1. Main -- Start. In onCreate, start a new Thread, and on it
>   instantiate and bind XService. 
>  2. Main -- Login screen. Get data,
>   package it in an Intent and broadcast to XService. 
>  3. XService --
>   Receive broadcast, unpack intent. Setup socket and data streams. Setup
>   LocationManager for updates. Broadcast to Main that the network is
>   ready. Upload data every time LocationManager updates. 
>   4. Main -- Upon receiving the network-ready broadcast, prepare Intent for initialization and broadcast. 
>  5. XService -- Receive
>   initialization-request broadcast, unpack, perform network task,
>   broadcast response. 
>  6. Repeat *ad nauseam* as per user
>   interaction and any timed updates. 
>  x. Main -- On logout,
>   broadcast to XService. 
>  x+1. XService -- Send logout info to
>   server, close sockets, broadcast to Main that it is exiting
>   gracefully, then stopSelf(). 
>  x+2 Main -- Complete logout
>   procedure.

My main question is -- is this the right way of going about it?

Another question is: What happens when XService broadcasts a Location update to Main, but Main is stopped (i.e. not running in foreground)? I assume that since the BroadcastReceiver on Main is not instantiated due to Main being in a stopped state, the broadcast essentially does nothing. How does this unreceived broadcast impact (or not, as the case may be) XService or the process / device in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That makes sense. My suggestion is starting the service on the main thread, then forming your new thread within the Service class. This would package the Service nicely so that you don't have to spawn a thread to use it, you can just call it.

If Main is stopped and the Broadcast sends a message, it's a lost message. You want to avoid those by registering the receiver at OnStart and unregistering at OnStop. You can save any pertinent information that the Activity may need to know in the Service itself.

An alternative to the Broadcast Receiver is the Messenger class. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)

Comment: Re: Thread in Service instead of Main: Good suggestion, thanks. It will certainly make keeping track of Threads easier. 

I assume that you meant that I should unregister the receiver onStop (rather than onStart). And when the activity starts up, it can just ask the Service for required information.

The Messenger class looks interesting. I'll have to do a little more research to see if it fits my needs better.

Comment: Ah yes that's what I meant. Yeah the messenger class is quite awesome, I used it for this app where I was constantly updating the activity with location data from a service. Are you planning on using newer location apis like locationServices or locationClient (now deprecated)?

Comment: Actually, my app is part of a study on Internet privacy, so the fewer parties involved in the computing, the easier it will be for me to analyze data. As such, I'll be using the plain android.location libraries and classes, so I won't have to factor Google Play Services (containing Location Services) in and out of my study.